# insert php td values to textarea after clicking button

Tags: php, jquery

I have echo PHP table with 3 tds:
1- checkbox.
2- names.
3- phone Numbers

I made textarea to contain all checked checkboxes tds phone Numbers into it.

I [tried to modificate this code](http://jsfiddle.net/Z9weS/) but it doesn't work with me.

My code :

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered TableStyle" id="table-scroll ">
    <thead>
        <th class="thead"><input type="checkbox" name="checkallnum" value="" id="checkallnum2" /></th>
        <th class="thead">Name</th>
        <th class="thead">Phone</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
             <td><input class="checkBoxClass" type="checkbox" name="check" value="" /></td>
             <td>AMMAR</td>
             <td>123456789</td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
             <td><input class="checkBoxClass" type="checkbox" name="check" value="" /></td>
             <td>Sara</td>
             <td>987654321</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
 </table>

<button type="button" id="confirmNums" class="btn btn-primary pull-left" style="">Add</button>

<textarea rows="8" name="" id="sendToNum" class="form-control" style="margin-bottom: 10px;" tabindex="1"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution is to use jQuery.

Maybe this example can get you started. When you click the 'Add' button, the phonenumbers will be added to the textarea.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#confirmNums').click(function() {
    var newline = "\n";
    var sendToNum = $('#sendToNum');
    sendToNum.text('');
    $("input[name=check]:checked").each(function() {
      var phoneNumber = $(this).parent().nextAll('td').eq(1).html();
      sendToNum.append(phoneNumber + newline);
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered TableStyle" id="table-scroll ">
    <thead>
    <th class="thead"><input type="checkbox" name="checkallnum" value="" id="checkallnum2" /></th>
    <th class="thead">Name</th>
    <th class="thead">Phone</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td><input class="checkBoxClass" type="checkbox" name="check" value="" /></td>
        <td>AMMAR</td>
        <td>123456789</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input class="checkBoxClass" type="checkbox" name="check" value="" /></td>
        <td>Sara</td>
        <td>987654321</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<button type="button" id="confirmNums" class="btn btn-primary pull-left" style="">Add</button>

<textarea rows="8" name="" id="sendToNum" class="form-control" style="margin-bottom: 10px;" tabindex="1"></textarea>
```

Comment: this is works very well. but what I need is to add this to add click function. so check first then click to add numbers. Thanks for your help

Comment: @ammoriz Ok, I see that you mean. I've updated the code. If you press the 'Add' button, the phonenumbers will be added to the textarea.